# How to add labels on the side of the gridview on the left column?

Tags: c#, gridview

I have an empty gridview and want to display it not only with headers, but also with a label column on the left side of each row. Should I create such label column in SQL and then bind it, or it's possible to add this via C# code?

p.s. number of rows is fixed in this table.

Answer (score 0):

Creating it is SQL will be a better option, 
if you want to modify the label name at a later stage it will be easy.
and if you enable sorting for the gridview, you don't have to add any new code.